# Need help traversing ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, traversal

> > Traverse the ArrayList created in (b) by the call to populate, reversing the sign of each number stored in the ArrayList.  Tip:  Use calls to get and set methods of Arraylist. Use calls to get(int index) and set(int index, E element). If necessary, method remove(int index) can be handy.
> >
> > Output all values stored in the ArrayList created and manipulated. 5 values 
> >     per line

I'm stuck on this part and I don't know what to do next. If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

**This is what my code looks like**

```
public class ArrayListPratice {


public static ArrayList populate(){
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i<100+(int)(Math.random()*100); i++)
        a.add(Math.random()*100-50);

    return a;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = -1;

    ArrayList <Integer> c = new ArrayList <>();                        



    while (a != 0){
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (a !=0){
            c.add(a);
        }

    }

    int sum = 0;
    int value = c.size();
    double avg = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++){
        sum += c.get(i);

    }
    avg= (double)sum/value;

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Sum of the values: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Amount of values: " + value);
    System.out.println("Average: " + avg);

    ArrayList b = populate();

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        c.get(i);
        c.set(i, value);




    }
```

Comment: It seems the instructions require you to use `get()` to retrieve the element at each index, and `set()` to store the sign-reversed value at the same index.  Since you're using the raw version of `ArrayList` (naughty!) you'll have to cast the type of the List elements to something useful.  `Math.random()` returns `double`, so your List elements should be of that type's wrapper class, `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your last `for` loop to following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
    double val = (double) b.get(i);
    b.set(i, -val);
}
```

Comment: It's giving me  java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer error

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    c.get(i);
    c.set(i, value);


}
```

with this

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        b.set(i, -b.get(i));
}
```